# How to deal with a dataset with "periods of time" and missing data

Tags: dataset, regression, cluster-computing, data-analysis, missing-data

I'm working on a dataset, which has as columns points in time (e.g. August, September, etc.) and as rows different measurements which were collected at that point.
Apart from that, the data is not clean at all, the are a lot of missing data and I just can't drop all the rows with them or filling them up so my idea was to divide the dataset in 4 smaller ones.
What kind of analysis can be performed on a dataset of this kind? Should I invert columns and rows?

Comment: You could invert the columns/rows and then perform time series imputation with a R package like imputeTS. If this actually makes sense depends a lot on your dataset.

Comment: I have very few observations and the dataset is made of satisfaction data by consumers. I have some doubts, but do you think it would be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timeseries regression with missing data is a special case within statistical analysis. Simply re-jigging the data set is not the solution.

I understand periodicity analysis and spectral analysis is performed to identify the sinosoid of best fit, i.e. a sine wave is driven through the missing data points and regression is one approach in identifying the fit to the existing data.

The same question has been previously raised on Stats exchange based on ARIMA (moving average). Personally, I am not overawed by this approach because there will be a specialist solution.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121414/how-do-i-handle-nonexistent-or-missing-data